# Rotating cusp catastrophe figure in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I made a cusp catastrophe figure with pgfplots but I can't seem to rotate it the way I want. The figure currently looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is the code I have been using:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y domain=-4:4,
          domain=-2:2,
          restrict z to domain=-5:5,
          samples=100,
          view={50}{8},
          mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
          colormap/blackwhite,
          xlabel=$Stress$,ylabel=$Connectivity$,zlabel=$State$,grid=both
         ]
\addplot3[surf] {-4*x^3 - 2*y*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me get the rotation that I want? Thanks so much in advance for helping me out!

Comment: You don't need the axes?

Comment: Not necessarily, but fine if they're there

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rotate` key in the `tikzpicture` options. But for this you have to get rid of the `axes`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=100]
\begin{axis}[y domain=-4:4,hide axis,
          domain=-2:2,
          restrict z to domain=-5:5,
          samples=100,
          view={50}{15},
          mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
          colormap/blackwhite,
          %xlabel=$Stress$,ylabel=$Connectivity$,zlabel=$State$,grid=both
         ]
\addplot3[surf] {-4*x^3 - 2*y*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! No, the axes are not necessary so this will work for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Angelique Glad it works for you. Please don't forget that you can accept the answers besides upvoting them.